# What happens when you install an OS that doesn't meet the minimum requirements of a computer?

Tags: memory, cpu, specifications

I have a  very old laptop. It has 256 MB RAM. I am trying to install an operating system which requires 512 MB of RAM. This is the only minimum requirement that my system does not have (But other specifications such as: CPU speed, video card etc. match the requirements.)

I am really curious to know if my system crashes when I install the OS or what exactly happens?

 And Can I install the OS in my computer?

Here are the CPU Specs and the OS requirement if you are interested:

CPU Specs:

- Laptop Model: Acer TravelMate 2420

  - Processor: 1.6GHz Intel Celeron
  - HDD: 40GB
  - **RAM: 256 MB ( up to 2GB extendable)**
  - Intel Graphics Media Accelerator (GMA) 900 - 128 MB
  - Display: 14.10 inch 16:10, 1280 x 800 pixel, WXGA.
  - Mainboard: Intel 945PM

Operating System:

- Name: Zorin OS Lite- 15.3

  - Architecture: x32 bit
  - iso: Zorin-OS-15.3-Lite-32-bit.iso
- OS system requirement:

  - CPU: 700 MHz Single Core – Intel/AMD 64-bit or 32-bit processor
  - **RAM: 512 MB**
  - Storage: 10 GB
  - Display: 640 × 480 resolution

Comment: You'll find out when you try it. It will either refuse to install, refuse to run, or operate like a three-legged donkey on roller skates trying to cross a cobbled street. I will not be a good experience. You can get a gig of RAM for that machine for €20

Comment: The computer you have is very low end spec. You have to try to see whatever works.